# How can I get text inside double brackets under cursor in Lua?

Tags: neovim, lua

I'm trying to write a simple little function to follow markdown wiki links of the form `[[wiki link]]`. I have a bunch of markdown notes with links of this type and they all link to files with the `.md` extension. The function would look something like this:

```lua
function follow-wiki-link()
  vim.cmd('e ' .. filename .. '.md')
end
```

Im planning to bind the function to some key like `gl`. So the problem lies in getting the filename under the cursor. Is there any way to get the text that is between double braces and under the cursor in Lua?

```
[[text to get]]
            ^cursor is here, for example
```

Thanks!

Comment: I highly suggest using `'path'` and `gf` (lots of ways to control `gf` linked at its help, like `'isfname'`, `'suffixesadd'`, `'includeexpr'`) to make this work: I do this for my personal wiki plugin. You'll get a lot more mileage out of builtins.

Comment: I'll look into those options thanks for mentioning them.